# Handler and Runnable Leaking

Tags: android

In my main splash activity, I have a handler that calls runnable which delays the next activity from starting. I have removed my static references, but I know that my handler is causing a memory leak.

```
public class MainSplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    private TextView heyDj;
    private ImageView spinninRecords;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        heyDj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hey_dj_intro);
        spinninRecords = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_album_splash);

        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        heyDj.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
        spinninRecords.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

        Animation mySpinAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.spin_logo);
        spinninRecords.startAnimation(mySpinAnimation);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LandingActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of creating a handler with a runnable, so it doesn't leak?

Comment: The simplest solution is to replace `new Handler()` with `spinninRecords` or one of your other views, as `postDelayed()` is available on `View`.

Comment: In Kotlin, if you don't reference anything from the enclosing class then the anonym object or lambda won't keep a reference to it. Something similar is likely true in java as well. In this particular case there may be no leaks at all. The question still stands though cause you may need to use a method from that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things being equal, if you have an option of not using a `Handler`, do not use a `Handler`.

In this case, since `postDelayed()` is available on `View`, you can switch to that and avoid any `Handler`-related shenanigans.

Comment: I don't understand, we cannot use handler in the onCreateView?

Comment: @Ticherhaz: I have not needed to use `Handler` in *years*. To be honest, at this point, I would consider the direct use of `Handler` by application code to be a code smell. `Handler` is *very* low-level. It is really for `AsyncTask`, Kotlin's `Dispatchers.Main`, RxJava's `AndroidSchedulers`, and things like that. App developers should be using those things that layer atop of `Handler`. And, for simple "run this on the main application thread, please", use `post()` and `postDelayed()` on `View`. There may be some IPC scenarios where we still need `Handler`, though.